# JavaScript-enabled checking routine works on Chrome/Opera/IE but not Firefox/Safari

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

I've written a short routine to check whether JavaScript is enabled on a browser.

It works on Chrome, Opera, and IE11. It does not work on Firefox or Safari; on those browsers it causes an infinite refresh loop. I want to understand why it's failing on Firefox and Safari, and how to make it work on those browsers.

I've whittled it down to 4 separate php files, provided below, which you may copy and run. With luck, you'll get the same success as I have had on Chrome, Opera, and IE, and the same failure on Firefox and Safari.

In brief: `index.php` makes an AJAX call written in pure JavaScript (i.e., no JQuery needed). By default, and firstly, `false.php` is copied to `body_message.php`, which later is included in `index.php` as its `<body>` message. If JavaScript is enabled in the browser, then the `<script>` section calls `ajax_copy_file.php`, which in turn will overwrite `body_message.php` with `true.php`. The result is that `index.php` will display a short message indicating whether JavaScript is enabled on the browser.

The JavaScript is minified, but with luck, seeing the full routine will not be necessary (even in the minification the main jist can be gotten).

This is index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript Test</title>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['JavaScript'])) {
    copy('false.php', 'body_message.php');
?>
    <script>var ajax={},hasAX=window.hasOwnProperty("ActiveXObject");ajax.x=function(){if(hasAX){for(var a="MSXML2.XmlHttp.6.0 MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0 MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0 MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0 MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0 Microsoft.XMLHTTP".split(" "),b,c=0;c<a.length;){try{b=new ActiveXObject(a[c]);break}catch(f){alert(f)}c+=1}return b}return new XMLHttpRequest};ajax.send=function(a,b,c,f,d){void 0===d&&(d=!0);var e=ajax.x();e.open(c,a,d);e.onreadystatechange=function(){4===e.readyState&&b(e.responseText)};"POST"===c&&e.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");e.send(f)};ajax.post=function(a,b,c,f){var d=[];Object.keys(b).forEach(function(a){d.push(encodeURIComponent(a)+"="+encodeURIComponent(b[a]))});ajax.send(a,c,"POST",d.join("&"),f)};function logStuff(a){"string"===typeof a?console.log(a):"object"===typeof a&&Object.keys(a).forEach(function(b){console.log(b+": "+a[b])})}ajax.post("ajax_copy_file.php",{copy_file:"true.php"},logStuff,!0);location.replace("index.php");</script>
<?php
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
unset($_SESSION['JavaScript']);
include('body_message.php');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is ajax_copy_file.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
copy($_POST['copy_file'], 'body_message.php');
$_SESSION['JavaScript'] = 'true';
echo 0;
exit;
?>
```

This is true.php:

```
<p>TRUE: JavaScript enabled</p>
```

This is false.php:

```
<p>FALSE: JavaScript disabled</p>
```

Why does this work on Chrome, Opera, and IE, but does not work (causing an infinite loop) on Firefox and Safari?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `location.replace("index.php")` code is placed after you send the XHR using `ajax.post`, but XHR requests are asynchronous, so you get redirected back before the `true.php`/`false.php` file has been copied. I'm guessing this is isolated to Firefox and Safari because other browsers either have heavy optimisations for XHR or just delay the `location.replace` for performance reasons. If you put the `location.replace` inside the XHR `readystate` event handler or the success function, it works in Firefox. See updated jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/j5qpwy9f/1/

Additional notes:

- Your object serialisation method is slightly incorrect; after running through `encodeURIComponent`, replace all `%20` with `+`, as this is the spec.
- I'm assuming that this isn't the final or production code but please stick to `<noscript>`. There are many flaws to your approach, least of which it uses AJAX, sessions, cookies, PHP, JS, 3 HTTP connections and a redirect to load a single page.

---

Use `<noscript>` tags for HTML to be parsed only when JavaScript is disabled.

```
<noscript>
    <style>
        #jsOnly {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</noscript>
<noscript>JavaScript is disabled</noscript>
<p id="jsOnly">JavaScript is enabled</p>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript

If you want an example, look at http://enable-javascript.com/ and its source.

Comment: I'm fully aware of <noscript>; I'm trying to discover why the routine I've written doesn't work on 2 of the 5 major browsers. I believe it has something to do with no response header being returned from the AJAX file when run in Firefox and Safari, but I'm uncertain. Try the routine and see.

Comment: @Tom I have updated the answer, but still strongly suggest an alternative method.